# Как сгруппировать выборку из 2-х таблиц с помощью join по условию

Tags: sql, oracle-study

Есть такое задание:
Путем соединения таблиц HR.DEPARTMENTS и HR.EMPLOYEES отобразить полные данные о департаментах, в которых минимальная зарплата ниже 5000.

Попробовал сделать так, но выводит ошибку

```
    select distinct d.department_id,department_name, d.manager_id, location_id from hr.departments d 
join hr.employees e on (min(e.salary) < 5000) order by 1
```

Ошибка: `group function is not allowed here`

Вот как выглядит hr.employees:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
   100   Steven           King     SKING    515.123.4567    17-JUN-03   AD_PRES   24000      -         -             90
```

hr.departments:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME MANAGER_ID  LOCATION_ID
10              Administration  200           1700
```

Comment: После ON должны быть поля, по которым Вы джоин делаете двух таблиц, а потом HAVING min ...

Comment: Что то я не особо понял как это должно выглядеть, обновил вопрос с добавлением примеры каждый таблицы

Comment: Поправил ответ см. ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот такой запрос

```
select 
    d.department_id
  , department_name
  , d.manager_id
  , d.location_id 
from hr.departments d 
left join hr.employees e on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id
  , department_name
  , d.manager_id
  , d.location_id
having min(e.salary) < 5000
```